# how can i use a deep network the same as other deep network?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder

I have an auto-encoder as we know this network is produced from 3 parts, Encoder, Decoder , latent space, I attached an image that shows my structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqYvJ.jpg
it has an auto-encoder in first part and after that I want to have an other encoder but the same as first encoder. now I want to know how can I force the structure that the second encoder was the same as first encoder ? please guide me about this problem.

Comment: Where is the attached image?

Comment: the question is vague, you want the secondary encoder to have the "same architecture" as the primary or you want the secondary to "share the weights" of the primary?

Answer (score 0):

The encoder is defined by it's graph (the operations to do) and the weights (the matrices/biases, etc). One is stored in the graph and the other in the session.

A new feature in tensoflow is the hub, which is supposed to facilitate transfer learning applications (like yours). Check out the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/creating). Here you would define the encoder as a module, train it, then import it when you want to train it with the DNN.

If you don't want to use that, you can use model save functions to read/write both the graph and the session. For example you could train the autoencoder then load the trained model and build the deep network on the embedding layer. You need to be careful if you want to freeze variables and do other such tricks.

Comment: thank you for your response. this image shows all of my network, the parts of image are not separate from each other. first I feed an image into auto-encoder then I change the latent space during learning and then I want to feed the output of autoencoder into same encoder to extract changed latent space and send it into other neural network to classify the changes. now I want to have same encoder in weights and graph. but I am not sure this work is true or not. I want to see the effect of changes in latent space

Comment: I find out my answer in another post that I put here. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337636/adding-data-to-decoder-in-autoencoder-during-learning?noredirect=1#comment91842284_52337636