# adding data to decoder in autoencoder during learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tensor

I want to implement an autoencoder using Keras and this structure is a large network that some operations is done on the output of autoencoder and then we should consider two loss I attached an image that shows my proposed structure. the link is below.

[autoencoder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtwIE.gif)

w has the same size as the input image and in this autoencoder, I do not use max pooling so the output of each phase has the same size as the input image. I want to send w and latent space representation to decoder part and then after adding a noise to the decoder output try to extract w using third part of the network. so I need that my loss function considers the difference between the input image and latent space representation and also between w and w'. but I have several problems with implementation. I do not know how can I add w to the decoder output, due to using this line "merge_encoded_w=cv2.merge(encoded,w)
" produce an error and does not work. I do not sure my loss function is true based on what I need or not?please help me with this code. I am a beginner and finding the solution is difficult for me. I asked this question before but no one help me with this. please guide me. my code is as below:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, Activation,UpSampling2D,Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GaussianNoise
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import regularizers
from keras import backend as K
import keras as k
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from time import time
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
# Embedding phase
##encoder

w=np.random.random((1, 28,28))
input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

x = Conv2D(8, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
#x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
#x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
merge_encoded_w=cv2.merge(encoded,w)
#
#decoder

x = Conv2D(2, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(merge_encoded_w)
#x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
#x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
#x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

#Extraction phase
decodedWithNois=k.layers.GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded)
x = Conv2D(8, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(decodedWithNois)
#x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
#x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
final_image_watermark = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)


autoencoder = Model([input_img,w], [decoded,final_image_watermark(2)])
encoder=Model(input_img,encoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss=['mean_squared_error','mean_squared_error'],metrics=['accuracy'])
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_validation=x_train[1:10000,:,:]
x_train=x_train[10001:60000,:,:]
#
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_validation = x_validation.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_validation = np.reshape(x_validation, (len(x_validation), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=5,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_validation, x_validation),
                callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder')])

decoded_imgs = autoencoder.predict(x_test)
encoded_imgs=encoder.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: Is `w` a data you feed or is it random array?

Comment: it can be a random array that is added during learning. what is the difference between these two things you said?

Comment: Just wondered why you add an random array and recover it.  A programmatic difference is that keras requires that the all data have the same save on the first dimension.  Anyways, I don't think you can use `cv2.merge` to merge tensors.  Use [Concatenate](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate) in stead.

Comment: if w was a data that is fed to network, what should I do? I want to send w and encoded output as a 28X28X2 filter to decoded part. is it possible? does concatenate do this for me?

Comment: when I use concatenate it produces this error "All inputs to the layer should be tensors"????

Comment: `w` also has to be a tensor, not numpy array.

Comment: I am not familiar with tensorflow and keras very well. can you please give me a sample code? if I want to define a tensor can I use this:"w = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 28,28,1), name="w")" if yes, how can I initialize it with random number? when I use this line"autoencoder = Model([input_img,w], [decoded,final_image_watermark(2)])
" it produces an error that w is a tensor and cannot use here?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of large architecture, I suggest you build from small pieces, then put the pieces together.  First, encoder part.  It receives an image of size `(28,28,1)` and returns the encoded image of shape `(28,28,1)`.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, GaussianNoise
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.models import Model

def make_encoder():
    image = Input((28, 28, 1))
    x = Conv2D(8, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(image)
    x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    encoded =  Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

    return Model(inputs=image, outputs=encoded)
encoder = make_encoder()
encoder.summary()

#_________________________________________________________________
#Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
#=================================================================
#input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 28, 28, 1)         0         
#_________________________________________________________________
#conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 8)         208       
_________________________________________________________________
#conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 4)         292       
#_________________________________________________________________
#conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 2)         74        
#_________________________________________________________________
#conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 1)         19        
#=================================================================
#Total params: 593
#Trainable params: 593
#Non-trainable params: 0
#_________________________________________________________________
```

The shape transition matches the theory.
Next, the decoder part takes encoded merged with another array, shape `(28, 28, 2)` and finally recovers original image, shape (28, 28, 1).

```
def make_decoder():
    encoded_merged = Input((28, 28, 2))
    x = Conv2D(2, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded_merged)
    x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
    decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x) 

    return Model(inputs=encoded_merged, outputs=decoded)
decoder = make_decoder()
decoder.summary()

#_________________________________________________________________
#Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
#=================================================================
#input_2 (InputLayer)         (None, 28, 28, 2)         0         
#_________________________________________________________________
#conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 2)         102       
#_________________________________________________________________
#conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 4)         76        
#_________________________________________________________________
#conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 8)         296       
#_________________________________________________________________
#conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 1)         73        
#=================================================================
#Total params: 547
#Trainable params: 547
#Non-trainable params: 0
#_________________________________________________________________
```

The model then tries to recover the W array as well.  Input is the reconstructed image plus noise (shape is `(28, 28, 1)`) .

```
def make_w_predictor():
    decoded_noise = Input((28, 28, 1))
    x = Conv2D(8, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoded_noise)
    x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    pred_w = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)  
    # reconsider activation (is W positive?)
    # should be filter=1 to match W
    return Model(inputs=decoded_noise, outputs=pred_w)

w_predictor = make_w_predictor()
w_predictor.summary()

#_________________________________________________________________
#Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
#=================================================================
#input_3 (InputLayer)         (None, 28, 28, 1)         0         
#_________________________________________________________________
#conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 8)         208       
#_________________________________________________________________
#conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 4)         292       
#_________________________________________________________________
#conv2d_11 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 1)         37        
#=================================================================
#Total params: 537
#Trainable params: 537
#Non-trainable params: 0
#_________________________________________________________________
```

With all pieces at hand, putting pieces together to build the entire model is not so hard.  Notice that the models you built above can be used like layers.

```
def put_together(encoder, decoder, w_predictor):
    image = Input((28, 28, 1))
    w = Input((28, 28, 1))
    encoded = encoder(image)

    encoded_merged = Concatenate(axis=3)([encoded, w])
    decoded = decoder(encoded_merged)

    decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded)
    pred_w = w_predictor(decoded_noise)

    return Model(inputs=[image, w], outputs=[decoded, pred_w])

model = put_together(encoder, decoder, w_predictor)
model.summary()

#__________________________________________________________________________________________________
#Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
#==================================================================================================
#input_4 (InputLayer)            (None, 28, 28, 1)    0                                            
#__________________________________________________________________________________________________
#model_1 (Model)                 (None, 28, 28, 1)    593         input_4[0][0]                    
#__________________________________________________________________________________________________
#input_5 (InputLayer)            (None, 28, 28, 1)    0                                            
#__________________________________________________________________________________________________
#concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 28, 28, 2)    0           model_1[1][0]                    
#                                                                 input_5[0][0]                    
#__________________________________________________________________________________________________
#model_2 (Model)                 (None, 28, 28, 1)    547         concatenate_1[0][0]              
#__________________________________________________________________________________________________
#gaussian_noise_1 (GaussianNoise (None, 28, 28, 1)    0           model_2[1][0]                    
#__________________________________________________________________________________________________
#model_3 (Model)                 (None, 28, 28, 1)    537         gaussian_noise_1[0][0]           
#==================================================================================================
#Total params: 1,677
#Trainable params: 1,677
#Non-trainable params: 0
#__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Code below trains the model with dummy data.  Of course, you can use your own so long as the shape matches.

```
import numpy as np

# dummy data
images = np.random.random((1000, 28, 28, 1))
w = np.random.lognormal(size=(1000, 28, 28, 1))

# is accuracy sensible metric for this model?
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([images, w], [images, w], batch_size=64, epochs=5)
```

**EDITS BELOW**

> I have some questions about the code that you put here. in the make_w_ predictor, you said:" # reconsider activation (is W positive?) # should be filter=1 to match W" what does it mean? W is an array that contains 0 and 1. what does it mean " reconsider activation" should I change the code for this part?

`relu` activation returns positive numbers in [0, +inf), so it may not be a good choice if `W` takes different set of values.  Typical choice would be the following.

- `W` can be positive and negative numbers: "linear" activation.
- `W` in [0, 1]: "sigmoid" activation.
- `W` in [-1, 1]: "tanh" activation.
- `W` is positive number: "relu" activation.

In the original code, you had:

```
w=np.random.random((1, 28, 28))
```

which takes values between 0 and 1.  So I suggested to switch from "relu" to "sigmoid".  But I did not change in my code sample because I was not sure if this was intended.

> you said the filter should be 1 it means change (3,3) to (1,1)? I am so sorry for these questions. but I am a beginner and I can not find some of these that you say. can you please help me and explain me completely.

I refer to this line in the original question:

```
final_image_watermark = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
```

If I understand correct, this defines `W'` in the attached image, which should predict `W` and its size is `(28, 28, 1)`.  Then the first argument to the `Conv2D` should be one.  Otherwise the output shape becomes `(28, 28, 2)`.  I made this change in my code sample because otherwise it emits shape mismatch error:

```
pred_w = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
```

I think `(3, 3)` part, `kernel size` in keras, is fine as is.

Comment: thank you very much for the response. it helps me and I learn how should I write code. but I have some other questions. I think this loss function only use w for computing accuracy. is it true? I want two loss functions. between the input image and the decoder output, and between w and w'. how can I write this mix loss function?

Comment: It uses both.  For multioutput model, keras computes the loss for each, and take average as the total loss.  https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models

Comment: I have some questions about the code that you put here. in the make_w_ predictor, you said:"  # reconsider activation (is W positive?)
    # should be filter=1 to match W" what does it mean? W is an array that contains 0 and 1. what does it mean " reconsider activation" should I change the code for this part? you said the filter should be 1 it means change (3,3) to (1,1)? I am so sorry for these questions. but I am a beginner and I can not find some of these that you say. can you please help me and explain me completely.

Comment: @maede I added answer to this comment.

Comment: if I want to have a loss function that contains the error for two parts 
 is this true or not? model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss={'decoder_output':'mse', 'extracted_w':'mse'}, metrics=['mae']) , 
the decoder_output is the name of decoder output and  extracted_w is the name of predict w output.

Comment: You can do so, but if you use same loss function for both outputs, you can simply give `loss='mse'`.  Then keras computes loss of each output by the same loss function.  https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models

Comment: thank you for the response. when I use tensorboard, I see different loss diagram in the output. which one is for w and which one is for decoder output. I am a little confused.
49999/49999 [==============================] - 13s 257us/step - loss: 0.2272 - model_30_loss: 2.9012e-05 - model_31_loss: 0.2271 - model_30_mean_absolute_error: 0.0025 - model_31_mean_absolute_error: 0.4558 - val_loss: 0.3167 - val_model_30_loss: 3.0745e-05 - val_model_31_loss: 0.3166 - val_model_30_mean_absolute_error: 0.0026 - val_model_31_mean_absolute_error: 0.4888

Comment: If you run my code sample as is, model_30 is the decoder and model_31 is for w.  loss is the weighted sum of the two.  To confirm this, check `model.summary()` to check the layer names.

Comment: thank you. how can I save the diagram of tensorboard for putting them in my report?

Comment: if I want to show the output of model and show the decoder and w_predictor on test data, how can I do it?

Comment: Well, these are new questions already.  I suggest you open separate questions.

Comment: thanks. but this is about this problem and I want to show the output of the model on test data. if I want to ask a new question I should put these code again? can you please guide me here.

Comment: You could show the same code as here, and what you want to do additionally. 
But Stackoverflow community is much more helpful if you show small example.  So make your code as small as you can without losing the point you want to ask.  In addition, "show the output of the model on test data" is a bit unclear.  You may want to ask either "how to encode test data" or "how to apply encoder and decode back with the test data", or "how to see the backed up version of W with test data", or something else if you mean different thing.

Comment: Hi again
if I want to visualize the output of each layer what should I do? because we used some functions and now I do not know how can I show the output of intermediate layers?